# how do I filter pins on Google Map pulled from a json api endpoint using Vue

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

I have a map with a number of pins on it, the pins are generated from an endpoint api (json). I want to filter the pins via an input that has a v-modal - the search criteria is already set up and is pulled from the same api.

Even if someone can give some tips as to where in the vue lifecycle the filter should happen, i.e mounted, updated computed ect

Originally I used this article as a reference

https://medium.com/@limichelle21/integrating-google-maps-api-for-multiple-locations-a4329517977a

```
created() {
    axios
        .get(
            `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/myEndpoint`
        )
        .then(response => {
            // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
            this.allProperties = response.data;
            this.markers = this.allProperties.map(function (x) {
                return {
                    lat: parseFloat(x.lat).toFixed(3),
                    lng: parseFloat(x.lng).toFixed(3),
                    add: x.dispAddress,
                    propId: x.property_id,
                    propPrice: x.outputAskingPrice,
                    propImg: x.imagePath
                };
            });
            this.allProperties = response.data.map(x => {
                x.searchIndex = `${x.sellingStatus} ${x.priceType} ${x.typeNames[0]} ${x.typeNames[1]} ${x.dispAddress}`.toLowerCase();
                return x;
            });
        });
},

mounted: function () {
    var _this = this;

    function initMap() {
        var center = {
            lat: 53,
            lng: -3
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
            zoom: 10,
            center: center
        });
        var newPin = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center,
            map: map
        });
    }
},

updated() {
    var _this = this;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        zoom: 9,
        center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(55.961, -3)
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
    var newPin;
    var count;
    for (count = 0; count < _this.markers.length; count++) {
        newPin = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                _this.markers[count].lat,
                _this.markers[count].lng
            ),
            map: map,
            icon: "../assets/img/map-pin.png"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(
            newPin,
            "click",
            (function (newPin, count) {
                return function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(`<a href="/properties/property?propertyId=${_this.markers[count].propId}"> ${_this.markers[count].add} </a> <p> ${_this.markers[count].propPrice}</p><img src="${_this.markers[count].propImg}"><p>`);
                    infowindow.open(map, newPin);
                };
            })(newPin, count)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `v-model` on an `<input>` field like mentioned in your question, you are binding the value of this `<input>` field to a variable probably defined in the `data` part of your Vue component. The value is always up to date in the model (reactive binding). You can watch this value and then trigger a function which updates Google Maps. Here is an example:

```js
Vue.component('demo', {
  data () {
    return {
      inputField: ''
    };
  },
  created () {
    console.log('Component script loaded, HTML not yet ready, load the data from your backend. Use a flag like isLoading or similar to indicate when the data is ready to enable input.');
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('Component mounted, HTML rendered, load Google Maps');
  },
  watch: {
    inputField (newValue) {
      console.log(`inputField changed to ${newValue}. Trigger here a method which update Google Maps. Make sure to debounce the input here, so that it does not trigger a Google Maps update too often.`);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="inputField" placeholder="Lookup place">
    </div>`
});

new Vue({ el: '#vue-demo-container' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue-demo-container">
  <demo></demo>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ssc-hrep3 I will start trying this just now

Comment: The problem I am still having is the v-modal is not bound to the google maps part in anyway (my bad explanation) the v-modal is bound to a list view of the items, not the map view. I am struggling to get my updated part connected to the filter....... if you know what I mean. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Because the google maps part is not a Vue component, you cannot bind props directly to it. You need to watch the property (which is bound with v-model) and then act on a change of that property. You can do it with a watcher like in my example. Each time the value changes, the watcher calls the function which then updates the Google Maps map.